# Некорректно переносит элементы массива в другой массив

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть массив `arr[a_size]` из 10 случайных чисел от -50 до 50 и два других массива, в которые переносятся элементы с основного массива, `arr1[a1_size]` (для положительных), `arr2[a2_size]` (для отрицательных). Проблема в том, что иногда не переносятся верхние отрицательные элементы массива `arr[a_size]` в массив `arr2[a2_size]`. Прикрепляю код и скриншоты:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    
    const int a_size = 10; 
    int a1_size = 0;
    int a2_size = 0;
    int arr[a_size];
    int arr1[a1_size]; 
    int arr2[a2_size];

    cout << "\nArray 'arr' with 10 random numbers from -50 to 50:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 101 - 50;
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0) {
            arr1[a1_size++] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "\nPositive elements of the array 'arr' are transferred to the array 'arr1':" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a1_size; i++) {
        cout << "arr1[" << i << "] = " << arr1[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            arr2[a2_size++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    cout << "\nNegative elements of the array 'arr' are transferred to the array 'arr2':" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a2_size; i++) {
        cout << "arr2[" << i << "] = " << arr2[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это Вам еще повезло.

Каковы здесь длины массивов `arr1` и `arr2`?

```
int a1_size = 0;
int a2_size = 0;
int arr[a_size];
int arr1[a1_size]; 
int arr2[a2_size];
```

Замените на

```
int a1_size = 0;
int a2_size = 0;
int arr [a_size];
int arr1[a_size]; 
int arr2[a_size];
```

Comment: Я так понял, что он каждый раз переопределяет переменные arr1 и arr2, увеличивая их размер на 1. Понятно, что это не очень. Но ведь должно же работать? Почему иногда работает, а иногда - нет?

Comment: @Leonid нет, не переопределяет. Объявлены массивы нулевой длины, и код переписывает память в стеке. Иногда - удачно, иногда - нет.

Comment: Ничего себе!!! То есть, он нелегально записывает дальше arr1[0] в память, а потом еще и нелегально читает? Это странно, почему области памяти не пересекаются, ведь объявлены подряд. И почему мусор тогда не выводится для других значений?

Comment: @Leonid "Это Вам еще повезло."

Comment: Ну в нулевые ячейки то он легально вписывает, там же постфиксный инкремент используется))) Так почему мусор не выводится? В соответствующих ячейках памяти всегда есть что интерпретировать как int. За пределы стека выходит запрос и блокируется? И почему компилятор на это не ругается или во время выполнения ошибки не выбрасываются?

Comment: @Leonid В какие "нулевые ячейки"? Массивы нулевой длины. "И почему компилятор на это не ругается" - ??

Comment: Понял, не ругайтесь, я C++ не знаю совсем, вот и спрашиваю.

Comment: Мне все-таки кажется, то и массив нулевой длины всегда будет обеспечивать сохранность данных в нулевой ячейке, разве нет? arr[0] <= arr <= указатель на первый элемент массива, разве нет?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать `vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    
    const int a_size = 10; 
    int arr[a_size];
    vector<int> arr1;
    vector<int> arr2;

    cout << "\nArray 'arr' with 10 random numbers from -50 to 50:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 101 - 50;
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0) {
            arr1.push_back(arr[i]);
        } else {
            arr2.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    cout << "\nPositive elements of the array 'arr' are transferred to the array 'arr1':" << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++) {
        cout << "arr1[" << i << "] = " << arr1[i] << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "\nNegative elements of the array 'arr' are transferred to the array 'arr2':" << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++) {
        cout << "arr2[" << i << "] = " << arr2[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Еще можно записать все значения в один массив того же размера, что и исходный. Просто сначала записать все положительные значения, увеличивая `mark_p` - размер части массива с неотрицательными значениями. После установить начальное значение `mark_n` (размер части массива с отрицательными значениями) равным `mark_p`.
Выводить значения уже из одного массива имея `mark_p` и `mark_n`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    
    const int a_size = 10; 
    int arr[a_size];
    int arr1[a_size];
    int mark_p = 0;
    int mark_n = 0;

    cout << "\nArray 'arr' with 10 random numbers from -50 to 50:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 101 - 50;
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0) {
            arr1[mark_p++] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "\nPositive elements of the array 'arr' are transferred to the array 'arr1':" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < mark_p; i++) {
        cout << "arr1[" << i << "] = " << arr1[i] << endl;
    }

    mark_n = mark_p;

    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            arr1[mark_n++] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "\nNegative elements of the array 'arr' are transferred to the array 'arr2':" << endl;
    for (int i = mark_p; i < mark_n; i++) {
        cout << "arr2[" << i << "] = " << arr1[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Для имитации вывода из разных массивов можно так:

```
cout << "\nNegative elements of the array 'arr' are transferred to the array 'arr2':" << endl;
for (int i = mark_p, j=0; i < mark_n; i++, j++) {
    cout << "arr2[" << j << "] = " << arr1[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```